# Background color of div only extends to bottom of h2 within div?

Tags: css, html, background-color

I am trying to create a row using Zurb Foundation on my site. For this row, I would like the background color to be red. For some reason, the background-color is only being applied to the h3 element inside the row. How can I make it so that the background color is applied to the whole row?

HTML:

```
<div class="redBG">
    <h3>NUMBERS</h3>
    <div class="large-4 columns"><a title="1" href="#"><img src="http://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg" alt="1"></a></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns"><a title="2" href="#"><img src="http://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg" alt="2"></a></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.redBG {
    background:red;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjCWp/)

Thanks!

Comment: The entire row is red as far as the browser is concerned - all the other elements in the `div` are floating, and as such not part of the layout for the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to the container div. This will then allow it to wrap the containing `div`'s

```
.redBG {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```